# Как перехватить событие о закрытии другой программы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Через Process.Start() запускается сторонняя программа. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при закрытии этой программы, она открывалась снова (этакая защита от закрытия окна программы). Как перехватить событие о закрытии окна программы и открыть ее снова?

P.S. Если использую событие Process.Exited, то оно срабатывает только при следующем запуске программы, т.е. прописать запуск программы в этом событии не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону WMI: https://https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx

Примеры легко гуглятся, например: http://fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-know-if-a-process-exited-or-started-using-events-in-c/

Answer (score 5):

Process.Start() + Process.WaitForExit() в отдельном потоке как вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Если не так важна скорость, можно раз в минуту к примеру проверять с помощью Process.GetProcessesByName

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx